# adding link values around each string

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink

I have a php value coming back from my database as a string, like

```
"this, that, another, another"
```

And I'm trying to wrap a separate link around each of those strings, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried a for loop, but since it's just a string of information and not an array of information that doesn't really work. Is there a way to wrap a unique link around each value in my string?

Comment: Can we see the for loop that you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way that I see to do this would be using PHP's `explode()` function. You'll find that it will become very useful as you start to use PHP more and more, so do check out its [documentation page](http://php.net/explode). It allows you to split a string up into an array given a certain separator. In your case, this would be `,`. So to split the string:

```
$string = 'this, that, another, another 2';
$parts = explode(', ', $string);
```

Then use a foreach (again, check the documentation) to iterate through each of the parts and make them into a link:

```
foreach($parts as $part) {
    echo '<a href="#">' . $part . "</a>\n";
}
```

However, you can do this with a `for` loop. Strings can be accessed like arrays, so you can implement a parser pattern to parse the string, extract the parts, and create the links.

```
// Initialize some vars that we'll need
$str = "this, that, another, another";
$output = "";  // final output
$buffer = "";  // buffer to hold current part

// Iterate over each character
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    // If the character is our separator
    if($str[$i] === ',') {
        // We've reached the end of this part, so add it to our output
        $output .= '<a href="#">' . trim($buffer) . "</a>\n";
        // clear it so we can start storing the next part
        $buffer = "";
        // and skip to the next character
        continue;
    }

    // Otherwise, add the character to the buffer for the current part
    $buffer .= $str[$i];
}

echo $output;
```

([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/j74sUntM))

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked wonderfully! And @Fred if in the link you add the $part to the end of each link then it gives you separate urls. Which is what I needed. Thank you again very much!

Comment: @zazvorniki ah ok. I see. Can you elaborate on that? I'm having a hard time understanding where exactly.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder - Great job, btw.

Comment: @Fred Thanks. I re-read the OP and I was mistaken, which is why I deleted my comment :P

Comment: @Fred, I ended up using codeigniters anchor and adding the parts to the end so I did get a unique link for each one as I needed them to link to different catagories, like this echo anchor('/catagory/'.$part,  $part);

Comment: @zazvorniki I don't use codeigniter, but am glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 1):

First [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string to get the individual words in an array. Then add the hyperlinks to the words and finally [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them.

```
$string = "this, that, another, another";
$words = explode(",", $string);

$words[0] = <a href="#">$words[0]</a>
$words[1] = <a href="#">$words[1]</a>
..

$string = implode(",", $words);
```

You can also use the `for` loop to assign hyperlinks that follow a pattern like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($words); $i++) {
   //assign URL for each word as its name or index
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to do it like this

```
$string = "this, that, another, another";
$ex_string = explode(",",$string);

foreach($ex_string AS $item)
{
   echo "<a href='#'>".$item."</a><br />";
}
```

Comment: Your answer would have the same link for each in the exploded string. The OP asked for a unique link.